# How do i create an ACTION file AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, action

I can not understand why I get an error on the page?

How do I save the random files I get?

Every time it shows me an error regarding both files

```
public class Captcha extends MovieClip
{
    public var captchaClip:MovieClip;
    public var reloadBut:SimpleButton;
    public var captchaText:TextField;
    public var captchaBG:MovieClip;
    private var captchaLoader:Loader = null;
    private var url:String = null;
    private var imageWidth:int;
    private var imageHeight:int;
    private var reloadButton:Object;

    public function Captcha()
    {
        this.captchaText.defaultTextFormat = TextFormats.format(14, true, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);
        this.captchaText.multiline = false;
        this.captchaText.restrict = "1234567890";
        this.reloadButton = getChildByName("reloadBut");
        if (this.reloadButton)
        {
            this.reloadButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.reloadButClick, 0, false, true);
        }
        return;
    }// end function

    private function reloadButClick(event:MouseEvent) : void
    {
        this.reset();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    }// end function

    public function getUserInput() : String
    {
        return this.captchaText.text;
    }// end function

    public function setUrl(param1:String, param2:int = 3, param3:int = 72, param4:int = 25)
    {
        this.url = param1;
        this.imageHeight = param4;
        this.imageWidth = param3;
        this.captchaText.maxChars = param2;
        return;
    }// end function

    public function reset()
    {
        this.captchaText.text = "";
        this.loadCaptcha();
        return;
    }// end function

    private function loadCaptcha()
    {
        this.captchaText.text = "";
        this.captchaLoader = new Loader();
        this.captchaLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.captchaLoaded);
        this.captchaLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.captchaLoadError);
        var _loc_1:* = new LoaderContext();
        _loc_1.checkPolicyFile = true;
        var _loc_2:* = new URLRequest(this.url + "?random=" + Math.random());
        this.captchaLoader.load(_loc_2, _loc_1);
        return;
    }// end function

    private function captchaLoadError(event:IOErrorEvent) : void
    {
        event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.captchaLoaded);
        event.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.captchaLoadError);
        return;
    }// end function

    private function captchaLoaded(event:Event) : void
    {
        event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.captchaLoaded);
        event.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.captchaLoadError);
        var _loc_2:* = event.target.content;
        _loc_2.height = this.imageHeight;
        _loc_2.width = this.imageWidth;
        this.captchaClip.addChild(_loc_2);
        return;
    }// end function

}
```

Do I need to build these files? If so what should be inside these ACTION files?

Here you can see the errors that are created for me:

[image]

Thanks for understanding (I'm pretty new to the language so help really got needed).

Comment: Please edit your question and place code in `code` blocks properly, your `}` currently outside the blocks.

Comment: I don’t understand you, you can edit the code please?

Comment: **(1)** Is Captcha supposed to be a PHP script or something? What (file or link) are you talking to when you call `/captcha?random=0.53499`? **(2)** Did you change anything from `Math.random()` line? Is it supposed to pick fractional numbers instead of whole numbers? **(3)** I've never heard of an `.action` file. Also your code does not load any such "action" file so I'm not sure how you got an error about ItemsData. **(4)** How did you know to use `?gender=1`? Have you seen a `.action` file before?

Comment: I do not know if it is a script but look at the code 2. I did not change anything in the code that way I got it 3. Strange

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement and/or connect to an existing CAPTCHA server that would provide your code with images and solutions. Your `localhost:8080` web server apparently does not know how to react on your CAPTCHA requests thus returns a 404.

Comment: But it's related to code look up should be a file that allows it